# SVGs not being mocked out in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jestjs

I'm trying to mock out calls to render SVG.

Here's my svgMock.js:

```js
export default "SvgrURL"
export const ReactComponent = "div"

export const BAD_SVG_URL = "/images/BAD_SVG_URL_THAT_WILL_FAIL_TO_LOAD.svg"
```

Here's my jest.config.js:

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
   ...
    '\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/tests/mocks/svgMock.js',
  },
```

And here's the call in the page:

```js
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import { SVGImage } from "../svg-image"

export const AppTest = () => <SVGImage src="./jobs-icon.svg" alt="jobs icon alt" />

test("renders JobsIcon", () => {
  render(<AppTest />)

  console.log(screen.debug())
  
  expect(screen.findAllByText("JobsIcon")).toBeTruthy()
})
```

Yet it always seems to trigger my msw mock:

```
  console.warn
    [MSW] Warning: intercepted a request without a matching request handler:
    
      • GET /jobs-icon.svg
    
    If you still wish to intercept this unhandled request, please create a request handler for it.
    Read more: https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/mocks
```

Thoughts?